# JQuery, Javascript - i can get all ID value in hasClass and save in list of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery, Javascript - i can get all ID value in hasClass and save in list of array
this is possible ?!

Comment: any tried code sample?expected results and inputs?

Comment: Yes that's possible, give it a try

Comment: Have you even tried this, or have you just come here and told us you want it?

Comment: hasClass will return true/false, not element it self, so, not sure that it will work as you expect in this case, please provide HTML.

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me, at least) what you are asking. Granted, there appears to be a language barrier, but please try to elaborate on your question. (Include what you have tried yourself.)

Comment: may be `arr = $(".yourClass").map(x => x.id).get()`

Comment: @Satpal return message x is not defined

Comment: `arr = $(".yourClass").map(function(){ return this.id}).get()`

Comment: @Satpal that is work thx u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
var arrayofelemnt=document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

then you can use any loop to get all element's id like

```
for(i in arrayofelemnt)
{console.log(arrayofelemnt[i].id)}
```